# Добавить приписку к URL с сохранением GET в htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, get

Как можно добавить приписку `.php` к URL по которому обращаются через `.htaccess` с сохранением параметров? Обращение вида `site.com/Add?id=1&count=2` надо отправить на `site.com/Add.php?id=1&count=2`. Количество `GET` параметров может быть разным, их может и вообще не быть.

Answer (score 0):

1. Убедиться, что поддерживается такой режим на сервере. Если это *Apache2*, то убедиться в работе модуля *mod_rewrite*
2. В корень положить файл *.htaccess* с содержимым:

   ```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^Add?id=(.*)&count=(.*)$ Add.php?id=$1&count=$2 [L, QSA]
   ```

Comment: А что если GET параметров будет другое количество? Часть параметров у меня будут необязательными.

Comment: @NTP, масштабировать аналогичным образом Add?param1=(.*)&param2=(.*)&param3=(.*)&param4=(.*)&param5=(.*) Add.php?param1=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3&param4=$4&param5=$5

Comment: Я так пониманию, это правило будет статичным, а что же делать, если один запрос будет содержать 5 параметров, а другой такой же 3? Можно ли всю GET часть перенести вне зависимости от количества параметров?

Comment: Она и так перенесется. Если запрос один и тот же, только разница в количестве параметров, то часть отсутствующих параметры передадутся пустыми.

Comment: Как альтернатива, можете передавать все в одном параметре, только в виде собственного вида пары ключ-значение. А дальше на сервере уже парсить их: *Add?q=param1:value1;param2:value2;param3:value3;...;paramN:valueN;* С точки зрения .htaccess тут будет 1 параметр, с точки зрения бизнес-логики - сколько угодно.

Answer (score 0):

Я считаю что можно делать редирект

```
Redirect site.com/Add?id=(.*)&count=(.*) site.com/Add.php?id=(.*)&count=(.*)
```

Comment: А что если GET параметров будет другое количество? Часть параметров у меня будут необязательными.

Comment: ну тогда не знаю ,можно прописать много редиректов на все случаи

Answer (score 0):

Код для неопределенного количество GET параметров, так же работает если GET вообще не будет

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)
RewriteRule ^Add?/$ Add.php?%1 [L]
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы (в частности, уточните, почему именно считаете написанное вами ответом на вопрос). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]